# Added time stamp in url in api request

Tags: php, jquery, api, rest

I'm building an API-centric Website and Mobile application. On my website, I create custom headers during my request to the api.

I'd noticed during one of the api request it was creating the following url

```
GET http://127.0.0.1/eapi/v1/es/fol?_=1433499279064
```

I did not add the trailing parameters (the one in bold),

GET http://127.0.0.1/eapi/v1/es/fol ***?_=1433499279064***

so here's my question:

1. who added it? (jquery ??)
2. is it safe that it has no param key (name) though a key is technically present (the _ underscore).

I'm using firefox 38.0.1, jquery 1.11

Answer (score 1):

It's normally added in by API's (such as `jQuery`) to stop the request from being cached, so you are guaranteed live results. It's perfectly safe.

---

Update: If you really did want to disable this (which you generally will not want to do) then you can do:

`jQuery.ajaxSetup({ cache:true });`

Which is explained the [`jQuery` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be
> cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work
> correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending
> "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for
> other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL
> that has already been requested by a GET.

Comment: so if i would choose to develop the request using xhr or native javascript, then i HAVE to add the time myself?

Comment: that explains it. i think, that's probably something i have missed during my read through.

Comment: If you were to code your own XHR request using native JavaScript then yes, the timestamp would *not* be added in. This is something `jQuery` in this instance has done to prevent browsers, namely IE, from caching the response and giving back stale data.